# No debug symbols being created for user modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kgdb

I want to debug a user module using kgdb .
The code :

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
int r_day,rday1=10;

static int hello_init(void)

{

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World");
    return 0;

}

static void hello_exit(void)

{

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye World");

}


module_init(hello_init);

module_exit(hello_exit);
```

The makefile:

```
_CFLAGS=-g

obj-m := hello-kernel.o

hello-kernel-objs := hello.o
```

I have my kernel compiled with proper debugging symbols (CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y).
But still when I check my sections in my module all the segments have address as 
0x0000000000000000.
Please help.

Comment: `_CFLAGS = -g -DDEBUG`?

Comment: @SD, `-DDEBUG` is redundant, `-g` is supplied as well. I suppose @Vinay has to remove that line completely from *Makefile*.

Comment: I take it that you are using this: https://www.linux.com/learn/kernel-newbie-corner-kernel-and-module-debugging-gdb - did you try "(gdb) add-symbol-file" as described there?  And please elaborate on "all the segments have address as 0x0000000000000000".

Comment: Hello, I want to debug my modules from a remote computer using kgdb (source code level debugging of modules ). But I am not able to generate debug symbols for my modules when I compile them. How I know this , is when I go to /sys/module/<my_module>/sections and check the different sections of my modules all have the same address i.e. 0x0000...000 .

Comment: Please tell me how can I add symbols to my modules so that I can add my symbols file to gdb via add-symbols command .

Comment: Presently when I am adding symbols the symbols file is getting added but when I try to put breakpoint in my fucntions I get the message (not in present context ) .

Comment: Did you check the files in sections as user or as root?  On my Ubuntu system (at random, module "drm"), if I read them as user I also get 0x0, but as root I get a value.